# Splitting two integers into separate variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, split, integer

Is it possible to split an input of two integers separated by a space such as '1 2' to be split into two separate variables? I have tried

```
ratio = input()
a,b = ratio.split(' ')
```

but it returns an error message of 'SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing'.

Answer (score 3):

Try using raw_input() instead of input()

`raw_input` strips trailing newline.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

Comment: It can't be a raw_input() because the numbers need to be integers

Comment: You can write it as `a,b = map(int, ratio.split(' '))`